# Multiple Argument Unpacking

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning argument unpacking and found it an useful feature where we can directly retrieve the values inside a list without writing extra lines of code.
e.g.,

```
def simplePrint(x,y):
      print x,y

myList = [3,4]

>>>simplePrint(*myList) #directly retrieve the values in myList ,storing the values in x & y and printing
3 4
```

but what if there are three, four,ten or hundred values in a list, for that we cannot pass that number of arguments in a function.So, for that I've tried this:

```
def simplePrint(*args):
      print args


myList = [3,4,5]

>>>simplePrint(*myList)
(3,4,5)
```

which is a tuple

So my question is am I doing anything wrong? or is there a way to retrieve the values directly like the first example.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `print` as function (using [`__future__` - Future statement definitions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html))

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>>
>>> def simplePrint(*args):
...       print(*args)
...
>>> myList = [3,4,5]
>>> simplePrint(*myList)
3 4 5
```

or simply call `print` function:

```
>>> print(*myList)
3 4 5
```

Comment: And while you're at it, ditch the `simplePrint` wrapper and just call `print` directly.

Comment: @user2357112, Ah... added a version that directly call `print`. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: The solution you gave is working well. I am getting the desired output. 

I want to know that why mine version is not working?
Why in my version's function simplePrint() cannot unpack the list values as your version did?

Comment: @Anand, In Python 2.x, `print` is statement by default. You can't use `*` operator there.

Comment: @Anand, Your code just print the `args` which is a tuple that contains all positional arguments pass.

Comment: @Anand, If you want to get the same output with `print` statement, you need to use some kind of loop. For example: http://ideone.com/hmJOXc